# VSCode Node.js intellisense and linting issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I have a couple of annoying issues with VSCode for some time. I'm on version 1.68.1 and working in Node.js on MacOS. For the purposes of this test, I created a setup as follows:

```
projectDir
 - package.json
 - logger.js
 - index.js
```

The `package.json` is inconsequential here but the other two files are as follows.

`logger.js`

```js
const logger = (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
}

module.exports = { logger };
```

`index.js`

```js
const { logger } = require("./logger");

someFunc();
logger("Hello!");
```

Here are the two things I'm struggling with:

1. Unimported functions are not flagged. For example, there's a call to `someFunc()` in `index.js` but VSCode has no problems with it. It's the same with undeclared variables. If I add `a = zz;` in the file, there are no warnings.
2. If I close the `logger.js` file, I can't autocomplete the import. What I mean is, if the `logger.js` file is open, then I can just type "logger" and select the import from the suggestions list, but it doesn't happen if the file is closed. I'm not sure if this is how it's supposed to be, but it's very annoying once there are more than 10-15 files in the project as I need to manually open them before VSCode becomes "aware" of their exports.

Sorry if this is all silly, but these two things have been impacting my workflow. Please feel free to ask for more info!

Comment: Spoke to a senior dev today and got an answer. The editor/IDE isn't a reliable tool for this. Instead, we should use some standard tooling (such as ESLint and/or TypeScript) to detect changes and produce an output right away. Getting ESLint working has been a struggle for me, but I hope these ideas help someone else!